# why is window.open(url) opening new window instead of tab

Tags: javascript

I am calling window.open(url) and Normally that would just open a new tab.
However, On this particular page i am developing, it's opening a while new small window.

i've also tried window.open(url, "_blank")

Does anyone know what would force the window to open a new window instead of a new tab.

thanks.

Comment: This is client behavior most likely, and therefore nothing you can do (programmatically) to change it. (btw, I assume you're [indirectly] citing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is completely up to the browser and how it chooses to handle it.  Most browsers open a new tab when _blank is used.  There is nothing that can be done programmatically to control the behavior.